# It is possible to embed the username on a Vimeo video running on the Moodle platform?

Tags: moodle, vimeo, vimeo-player

I run my private Vimeo videos on several courses on my Moodle website and there has been illegal sharing via screen recording of the content by moodle students. An alternative to avoid piracy would be to display the name and ID of the Moodle user when playing the video

Tried to embed the username using css but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe embed your url + copyright in the original video?